# Hypergeometric function

Tags: stochastic-calculus, hypergeometric-functions, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that $V$ follows the mean reverting process $$dV=η( ̅V-V)Vdt+σVdz$$
I want to find the optimal investment rule, and using Itos's lemma I get that the differential equation that $F(V)$ must satisfy

$$ 1/2 σ^2 V^2 F''(V)+[r-μ+η( ̅V-V)]VF'(V) -rF = 0$$
$F(V)$ must satisfy the boundary conditions

$$F(0)=0$$

$$F(V^* )=V^*-I$$

$$F' (V^* )=1$$

The solution is stated to be given by: 
$$F(V)=AV^θ H(2η/σ^2  V;θ,b)$$
The solution is a confluent hypergeometric function $H(x;θ,b(θ))$ 
How do I solve for $V$ and $A$?

I have calculated the value for $θ$ and $b$. But I don't know how to proceed.
In the book it says that $A$ is a constant to be determined. We find $A$ as well as the critical value $V^*$ at which it is optimal to invest, from the remaining two boundary conditions.

And hence I am lost.

Because the confluent hypergeometric function is an infinite series, $A$ and $V^*$ must be found numerically. What does this mean? Isn't there an analytical closed form solution here?

How do I solve for $$dH/dv$$ and $H$
from eq.

$$(v*)^2+v*H(θ-1)-Iv*dH/dv-IHθ=0$$
I know $I$,$θ$ and $b$.

See http://web.mit.edu/rpindyck/www/Courses/RO_P2_Hand%20Outs.pdf from slide 42 down for the whole set of equations.. 
and the example from http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/ensino/downloads/mestrado_profissional_projeto_fim_curso/projetos_fim_cursos_2010/Diogo_Duarte.pdf
on p.22-25

Comment: In general, hypergeometric functions are transcendent, which means that no closed-form expression for the inversion problem you're looking at can be found in terms of other known special functions. It may happen though that your particular problem is solvable explicitly, but this can only happen by accident. As for your last question, you want to solve a differential equation linear in $H$ (since your notations are ambiguous I can't decide whether your equation is also a difference equation in $\theta$). This question has answers in differential Galois theory, try a search on the site.

Comment: I was told I had to impose taylor series. To find a solution to the hypergeometric function, but i', unsure how to do that

Comment: and the second question is just a rearanging of the hypergeometric function. see link